# Three Monitor Setup with P2419HC + Intel graphics using daisy chain

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, intel-graphics, display-resolution, usb-c

I'm trying to daisy chain three Dell P2419HC displays to my ThinkPad X1, but the third display doesn't accept the desired resolution of 1920x1080. Setup looks like this:

System

- i7-1165G7, Intel Iris Xe graphics
- Ubuntu 20.04.4, Kernel 5.14.0-1027-oem
- GNOME 3.36.8

Connection (see below for an update)

```
X1 <--USB-C--> Display 1 (MST On, also has peripherals and USB-to-CAT attached)
<--DP--> Display 2 (MST On)
<--DP--> Display 3 (MST Off)
```

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4440 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     60.03 +  59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-3-8 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3-1-8 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3-1-1 connected 600x800+3840+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00*   60.32 
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

As you can see, DP-3-1-1 is connected with 800x600 @ 75.00. Changing it to any higher resolution/rate combination than 800x600@75, I get an error (640x480 or 720x400 do work as well):

```
CptSnuggles@CptSnugglespc:~$ xrandr --output DP-3-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 -r 60
xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed
```

I checked the Dell documentation for correctly chaining the displays and the Intel help pages about my graphics driver if it actually supports my wanted setup. Everything looks possible and correct to me, I don't know what's wrong here. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update**: So, I fixed it by attaching two USB-C cables to my laptop.

Connection

```
X1 <--USB-C--> Display 1 (MST On, also has peripherals and USB-to-CAT attached) <--DP--> Display 2 (MST Off)
X1 <--USB-C--> Display 3 (MST Off)
```

xrandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4920 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     60.03 +  59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-3-8 connected 1920x1080+1920+402 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3-1 connected 1080x1920+3840+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2-8 connected primary 1920x1080+0+402 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

I'm wondering if there is maybe a limitation regarding too many things attached through a single USB-C cable?